# Open sqlite database fails android

Tags: android, sqlite, database-design

I have several tables to be inserted into a database and have created separate java classes for each files. I am new to sqllite. SO had the following queries. Please help from your expertise

1) When i run create and open database, it catches the exception, but when i change the version number, it runs normally. What does this version signify??

2) For each creation of the new table, should i have to increment the version??

3) Also, if i have to create tables to the same database, then i have to keep the database name, helper name same in all the classes i create??

4) Can i delete a version so that i can reuse them?? Or drop this database entirely?? So that i can recreate everything from the beginning?

5) Lastly where can i see the database files?? many forums suggested it will be in data/.. folder but my data/.. folder remains empty always.

Please share your expertize and oblige.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The version number signifies a newer version of the database, i.e. a modification to it's schema.

2) The creation of new tables changes the database schema, so you should increment the version.

4) From my experience, you can delete a database by using the 'adb uninstall your package', this is especially helpful if you have a content provider.  The uninstall also removes the content provider.
If you want to restart from a given point and say add tables to your database and re-test until you get it right you would do the adb uninstall ... and put a copy of your starting database in your projects asset folder and then use the supplied code to re-create the database if it doesn't exist.

5) There area several ways you can see your database files. 
 have used 2 stand alone programs on my Windows 7 platform; SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1 and sqlitestudio. If you are using eclipse you and add the plugin SQLLIteManager, com.questoid.sqlitemanager_1.0.0.jar.

Hope this helps.

Here's my source code  from my dbhelper where I copy a database for the project if it doesn't exist.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class TDAdbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

     private static String DATABASE_PATH;
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tda.db";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private Context context;
 private SQLiteDatabase db;

 TDAdbHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  this.context = context;
  String packageName = context.getPackageName();
  DATABASE_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
  Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... before calling openDatabase ");
openDataBase();
  Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... after return openDatabase ");
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... Starting TDAdb.onCreate ");
  TDAdb.onCreate(db);
 }

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  TDAdb.onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
 }
 //Performing a database existence check
 private boolean checkDataBase() {
     Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... Starting checkDatabase ");
     SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
     try {
         String path = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
         checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                       SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
     } catch (SQLException e) {
         Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
     }
     //Android doesn’t like resource leaks, everything should 
     // be closed
     if (checkDb != null) {
         checkDb.close();
     }
     return checkDb != null;
 }

 //Method for copying the database
 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
     //Open a stream for reading from our ready-made database
     //The stream source is located in the assets
     Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... in copyDataBase ");
     InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

      //Path to the created empty database on your Android device
     String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

      //Now create a stream for writing the database byte by byte
     OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

      //Copying the database
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int bytesRead;
     while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
         localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
     }
     //Don’t forget to close the streams
     localDbStream.close();
     externalDbStream.close();
 }
 //This piece of code will create a database if it’s not yet created
 public void createDataBase() {
     Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "... in createDataBase ");
     boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
     if (!dbExist) {
         this.getReadableDatabase();
         try {
             copyDataBase();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
             throw new Error("Error copying database!");
         }
     } else {
         Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
     }
 }

 public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
     String path = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
     Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Starting openDatabase " + path);
     if (db == null) {
        createDataBase();
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
             SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
     }

     return db;  
}

}
```

Notice the modification I've made in the db.java

*

```
/*   private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
      "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + CHAPTER_TABLE + " (" +
       KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
       COL_CHAPTER + "," +
       COL_CHAPTERTITLE + "," +
    //   KEY_CONTINENT + "," +
       " UNIQUE (" + COL_CHAPTER +"));"; */

     public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
          Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
     }

     public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
      onCreate(db);
     }
}
```

*