# Issue with my android db file?

Tags: android, sqlite

Before 2 hours i have pulled my db file from eclipse file explorer that time it was having all the data. but now when i check by pulling the db file it has only one table android_metadata nothing else i was shocked 
why this happening ?
can any one explain ?

my complete db code

```
    package com.example.istudy;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.AvoidXfermode;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.dbtable.ProfileTable;
import com.example.dbtable.Sem5;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "iStudy";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "sem5";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME2 = "profile";


    //columns
    private static final String KEY_SUBJ = "sub_name";
    private static final String KEY_CHAP = "total_chapters";
    private static final String KEY_CHAP_COMPLETED = "chap_completed";
    private static final String KEY_CHAP_REMAINING = "chap_remaining";

    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_SEM = "sem";
    private static final String KEY_COLG_TIMING = "colg_timing";
    private static final String KEY_STUDY_HOURS = "study_hours";
    private static final String KEY_TERM_START = "term_start";
    private static final String KEY_TERM_END = "term_end";


    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(Profile.getTag(), "oncreate (...) is ececuting ...");

        String create_table = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME1 + " ( " + KEY_SUBJ + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY , " + KEY_CHAP + " INTEGER , " + 
        KEY_CHAP_COMPLETED + " INTEGER, " + KEY_CHAP_REMAINING + " INTEGER " + " )";
        db.execSQL(create_table);

        create_table = null;

        create_table = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + " ( " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_SEM + " INTEGER ,  " + KEY_COLG_TIMING + " TEXT ," + 
        KEY_STUDY_HOURS + " TEXT , " + KEY_TERM_START + " DATE , " + KEY_TERM_END + " DATE  )";
        db.execSQL(create_table);

        Log.d(Profile.getTag(), "After creating table inserting sem5 table data");

        insertInSem5Table(db);


    }

    private void insertInSem5Table(SQLiteDatabase db ){
        String[] subName = {"ADBMS","CN","EVS","MP","TCS"};

        for (int i = 0; i < subName.length; i++) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_SUBJ, subName[i]);

                if( !(subName[i].equals("MP")) ){
                    values.put(KEY_CHAP, 8);

                }
                else{
                    values.put(KEY_CHAP, 7);
                }

                values.put(KEY_CHAP_COMPLETED, -1);

                if( !(subName[i].equals("MP")) ){
                    values.put(KEY_CHAP_REMAINING, 8);

                }
                else{
                    values.put(KEY_CHAP_REMAINING, 7);
                }

                long insert = db.insert(TABLE_NAME1, null, values);
                Log.d(Profile.getTag() , String.valueOf(insert)) ;


        }

        Log.d(Profile.getTag(), "closing the db after inserting sem5 data");
        db.close();

    }

    public void insertProfileData(String name, int sem, String colgTimingFrom, String colgTimingTo, String studyHourFrom, String studyHourTo, 
            Date termStart, Date termEnd ){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        values.put(KEY_SEM, sem);
        values.put(KEY_COLG_TIMING, colgTimingFrom + " " + colgTimingTo );
        values.put(KEY_STUDY_HOURS, studyHourFrom + " " + studyHourTo );
        values.put(KEY_TERM_START, termStart.toString() );
        values.put(KEY_TERM_END, termEnd.toString() );
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME2, null, values);
        Log.d(Profile.getTag(), "values inserted successfully ....");
        db.close();
    }

    public List<Sem5> getAllRecordsOfSem5Table( ){
        List<Sem5> list = new ArrayList<Sem5>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME1;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if( cursor.moveToFirst() ){
            do{
                Sem5 sem5 = new Sem5();

//              int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SUBJ);
//              int columnIndex2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHAP);
//              int columnIndex3 = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHAP_COMPLETED);
//              int columnIndex4 = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHAP_REMAINING);
//              
//              
//              
//              Log.d("naved " , cursor.getString(columnIndex));
//              Log.d("naved " , cursor.getString(columnIndex2));
//              Log.d("naved "  , cursor.getString(columnIndex3));
////                Log.d("naved "  , cursor.getString(columnIndex4));
//              String string = cursor.getString(columnIndex4);
//              if( string == null )
//                  Log.d("naved chap_remaing " , " null " );
//              else
//              Log.d("naved chap_remainig " , string);


                sem5.setKEY_SUBJ(cursor.getString(0));
                sem5.setKEY_CHAP(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                sem5.setKEY_CHAP_COMPLETED(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
                sem5.setKEY_CHAP_REMAINING(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                list.add(sem5);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
        return list;

    }

    public List<ProfileTable> getAllRecordsOfProfileTable( ){
        Log.d(Profile.getTag(), "Getting all records of profile table ....");

        List<ProfileTable> list = new ArrayList<ProfileTable>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME2;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if( cursor.moveToFirst() ){
            do{
                ProfileTable profileTable = new ProfileTable();
                profileTable.setKEY_NAME(cursor.getString(0));
                profileTable.setKEY_SEM(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                Date colgTiming = null, studyHrs = null, termStart = null, termEnd = null;
                try {
                     colgTiming = java.text.DateFormat.getInstance().parse(cursor.getString(2));
                     studyHrs = java.text.DateFormat.getInstance().parse(cursor.getString(3));
                     termStart = java.text.DateFormat.getInstance().parse(cursor.getString(4));
                     termEnd = java.text.DateFormat.getInstance().parse(cursor.getString(5));
                     profileTable.setKEY_COLG_TIMING( colgTiming);
                     profileTable.setKEY_STUDY_HOURS(studyHrs);
                     profileTable.setKEY_TERM_START(termStart);
                     profileTable.setKEY_TERM_END(termEnd);
                     list.add(profileTable);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    db.close();
                    return null;
                }


            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        Log.d(Profile.getTag(), "Closing db ....after getting profile table...");
        db.close();
        return list;

    }




    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

My activity code

```
public class Profile extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "iStudy";

//private DBHandler dbHandler;

public static String getTag() {
    return TAG;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(this);

    Log.d(TAG , "Retriving profile data ...");

    List<ProfileTable> allRecordsOfProfileTable = dbHandler.getAllRecordsOfProfileTable();


    if( allRecordsOfProfileTable == null || allRecordsOfProfileTable.size() == 0 ){
        Log.d(TAG , "Retrived profile record ..it was either null or allRecordsOfProfileTable.size() == 0 ... so starting profile_activity");
        setContentView( R.layout.profile_screen );
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG , "Retrived profile record ..it was not null so starting home_activity");
        setContentView( R.layout.home_activity ) ;
    }

     Button nxtBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nxtBtn);
     nxtBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    } }
```

i am showing you only the relevant code if you want more info please ask.

for any one who wants more log info then please refer this

1. 06-30 11:22:43.579: D/iStudy(869): Retriving profile data ...
2. 06-30 11:22:43.579: D/iStudy(869): Getting all records of profile
   table....
3. 06-30 11:22:43.949: D/iStudy(869): oncreate (...) is ececuting ...
4. 06-30 11:22:44.079: D/iStudy(869): After creating table inserting
   sem5 table data
5. 06-30 11:22:44.093: D/iStudy(869): 1
6. 06-30 11:22:44.201: D/iStudy(869): 2
7. 06-30 11:22:44.209: D/iStudy(869): 3
8. 06-30 11:22:44.309: D/iStudy(869): 4
9. 06-30 11:22:44.416: D/iStudy(869): 5
10. 06-30 11:22:44.416: D/iStudy(869): closing the db after inserting
    sem5 data
11. 06-30 11:22:44.419: I/SQLiteConnectionPool(869): The connection pool
    for /data/data/com.example.istudy/databases/iStudy has been closed
    but there are still 1 connections in use.  They will be closed as
    they are released back to the pool.
12. 06-30 11:22:44.439: D/AndroidRuntime(869): Shutting down VM
13. 06-30 11:22:44.439: W/dalvikvm(869): threadid=1: thread exiting
     with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
14. 06-30 11:22:44.671: E/AndroidRuntime(869): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
15. 06-30 11:22:44.671: E/AndroidRuntime(869):
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
     ComponentInfo{com.example.istudy/com.example.istudy.Profile}:
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an
     already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:
     /data/data/com.example.istudy/databases/iStudy.

Comment: did you do some database updates?

Comment: share your code so we can help you.

Comment: I can explain.  You have a bug in your code. SQLlite does mot just lose data.

Comment: i solved it just removed onclose() ....

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your code, there is currently no correlation between the database in your asset folder and your application, other than the database is in the asset folder.

I would expect that at some point your app was uninstalled, maybe via debug and the database was then fresh, no table and if you didn't get to the code to create the new table, the result is an empty database.

If you want to copy your database in the asset folder into your application at run time you'll have to do something like in my answer on [Open SQLite database fails Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103831/open-sqlite-database-fails-android/16989383#16989383)

There are several tools to work with sqlite database, such as sqlitestudio, sqliteadmin, sqlitedatabasebrowser, etc. to access and maintain your database in the asset folder.
Hope this helps.